# Как заинжектить классы модели в presenter?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp, dagger2

До недавних пор я писал весь код работы с базами данных и сетью прямо в presenter(MVP moxy).
Сейчас я хочу изменить это и как я понял и мне подсказали необходимо создать класс для работы с сетью, базой данных и тд, на каждый свой. И самое главное - презенер инжектить во view - activity/fragment.А уже классы модели в презентер. Вот я не конца понимаю, как заинжектить классы модели в презентер?до этого я с помощью dagger 2 инжектил классы во view и далее передавал как аргументы в функции презентера. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете все зависимости прокинуть в конструктор `Presenter-a` и указать аннотацию `@Inject`.

```
class Presenter @Inject constructor (
    private val cahce: Cache,
    private val remote: Remote
){
    // some code
}
```

Далее в `Activity` вы просто инжектите презентер:

```
class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: Presenter
}
```

Ну и соответственно нужно помнить, что все зависимости `Remote` и `Caсhe` так же должны быть прописаны в модулях или через аннотацию `@Inject`.

В целом можно презентер и не через конструктор инжектить, как в примере, а просто прописывать `@Provide` метод в модуле аналогично любому другому классу.

Comment: Presenter у меня уже заинжекчен во View с помощью аннотаций moxy. Вопрос в том,как класс работы с базой данных,например, присоединить к презентеру что бы работать там с ним. Без присоединения этого класса бд к View. Ну или я не до конца понял ответ

Comment: Просто положите его в конструктор презентера. А в одном из модулей даггера вы должны рассказать даггеру как ему получать вашу БД.

Comment: @kernokus, вот тут описано как dagger&Moxy использвать вместе: https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/issues/100